# How can I keep a flutter app alive in background?

Tags: android, flutter, service, background, foreground

I'm making a running app that tracks the users when they're running. For this to work I have to be able to keep the app running in the background for the entire run, which in some cases can be over an hour long.

I've managed to keep tracking in the background for shorter periods of time using [Background Locator](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator), however, the app shuts down at what seems to be unpredictable times. One time it lasted for over 50 minutes, another only 13 minutes. The plugin I'm using sets up a foreground service, but that does not seem to be enough to keep the app alive...

For now, I'm only running on Android. Could this be some limitation of the Android operating system? If so, is there something I can do about this to keep the app running in the background for long periods of time?

Comment: Look through battery settings and see if you can exclude your app from battery optimizations. This part of android behavior is not uniform across different manufacturer implementations - they can be more or less aggressive and may treat stuff like usage of sensors/gps as a hint to shut down your service sooner.

Comment: With the app set to not optimize I get the same result